# How to change the ID of a complex type property in entity framework without first selecting the object?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, entity-framework

If I have Object A with a property of complex type Object B, how can I change A.B to another B object without first selecting the new B object?

For example, I know I can do this

```
A.B = (From b In db.Bs Where b.Id = NewID Select b).First()
```

But I would rather do something like this

```
A.B.Id = NewID
```

And I assume I can't do this because I would overwrite the properties of the existing B object to empty values

```
B = New B With { .Id = NewID }
db.Bs.Attach(B)
A.B = B
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have the `A.B` property call a constructor on demand when `B` is not yet initialized.

I converted this from C# to VB.NET without testing it, but same pattern works everywhere. Just make sure you initialize the property to `Nothing` or `null` first, and in the property accessor call the constructor if the private member variable is not initialized. Then return the value as usual.

```
Public Class B
    Public Property Id() As [String]
        Get
            Return m_Id
        End Get
        Set
            m_Id = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Id As [String]
End Class
Public Class A
    Private _B As B
    Public Sub New()
        _B = Nothing
    End Sub
    Public Property B() As B
        Get
            If _B Is Nothing Then
                _B = New B()
            End If
            Return _B
        End Get
        Set
            _B = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

And then you can set properties on A.B with impunity!

```
Dim a As New A()
a.B.Id = "B was created on demand!"
```